# How to show the same element when hovering a li using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an overlay effect when hovering on a `<li>` element inside a `<ul>`.
I want this element to be common to every `<li>`.

My first idea was to put an additional element, like a `<div>`, inside the list.
Sketchy example:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <div></div>
</ul>
```

```
ul div {
   opacity: 0
}
li:hover ~ div {
   opacity: 1
}
```

However, we can't put any tag inside a `<ul>` other than a `<li>`, because it would be considered invalid markup.

Since there is no way to select the parent of an element, is there any way to resolve this issue using CSS only?

Comment: you can wrap the div into an li or use an empty li with and id or a class . li ~ li.myLast. it can also be a pseudo li:hover::after

Comment: Would a tooltip effect serve your needs? Tooltip libraries are everywhere. I'm sorta curious if your use case is actually unique such that a tooltip wouldn't suffice.

Comment: But your HTML isn't valid. The `div` can't be a direct child of `ul`.

Comment: @G-Cyr I had also considered the last (empty) li, but that would cause a lot of changes to my CSS because it's using too many li selectors. But I consider this solution a lot to do what I need, I think probably in the end it will be this one.

Comment: @Marc Not really, but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements if your needs are simple.

If you are trying to use a child element to select a parent element, that is not curently possible: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Minimal Example:

```css
li:hover:after{
  display:inline-block;
  content:"pseudo element";
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
</ul>
```

Extended example with some attribute defined text:

```css
ul li:hover:before, li:hover:after{
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  float:right;
  content:attr(data-myMessage);
  animation-duration: 250ms;
  animation-name: slidein;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color:#bada55;
}

li:hover:after{
  animation-name: slideinleft;
  opacity:0%;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 10rem;
    opacity:0%;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0rem;
    opacity:100%;
  }
}

@keyframes slideinleft {
  from{
    margin-left: -10rem;
    opacity:0%;
  }
  
  to {
    margin-left: -1rem;
    opacity:100%;
  }
 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li data-myMessage="message">aaa</li>
    <li data-myMessage="something">bbb</li>
    <li data-myMessage="bottle">ccc</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm trying to do, but thank you for the response. Yes, unfortunately it is not possible at the current state of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background color on `:hover` pseudo class. You can also use `:before` and/or `:after` as well.